# ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer and ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on heroku with mobile testing through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to test multiple mobile user agents with selenium and chrome. I'm using python 3.6 and deploying to heroku. Based on http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation .

You can download my project for both windows and heroku use at:

```
https://github.com/kc1/mobiletest
```

(keep in mind that if you deploy to heroku you have to set FLASK_CONFIG to production. Also please note that the code in the project is slightly different than in this question because I've been playing with the code over the past week.)

I have:

```
def some_long_calculation():
    driver = create_chromedriver('kkk')
    # driver = create_chromedriver()

    driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/")
    .....
```

and :

```
def create_chromedriver(ua=False):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = os.getenv('$HOME') or basedir+'/chromedriver.exe'
    FLASK_CONFIG = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')

    if ua:

        mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "Nexus 5"}
        options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)


    if FLASK_CONFIG and FLASK_CONFIG == "production":
        CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'
        GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM = os.getenv('$GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM') or 'no path found'
        options.binary_location = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'

        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

    return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

If I run it locally with the mobile browser enabled It works as expected:

[image]

If I run it on heroku with the mobile browser enabled :

[image]

Then I tried it on heroku with the mobile user disabled I get:

[image]

So at least I know the setup is working as far as chrome and chromedriver.

heroku Logs:

```
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967643+00:00 app[web.1]:     driver = create_chromedriver('kkk')
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967637+00:00 app[web.1]:     png = some_long_calculation()
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967645+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/main/cl.py", line 120, in create_chromedriver
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967640+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/main/cl.py", line 123, in some_long_calculation
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967648+00:00 app[web.1]:     return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967651+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967654+00:00 app[web.1]:     desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967656+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967659+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967661+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967669+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967664+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967667+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 318, in execute
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967672+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967674+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967677+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 496, in _request
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967679+00:00 app[web.1]:     resp = self._conn.getresponse()
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967682+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967685+00:00 app[web.1]:     response.begin()
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967687+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967695+00:00 app[web.1]:     line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967690+00:00 app[web.1]:     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967698+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967692+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967700+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._sock.recv_into(b)
2018-07-15T17:37:53.967712+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Thanks for your detailed answer. I've changed the code to incorporate the flags you mentioned. Chrome version is 67.0.3396.99. Chromedriver is 2.40 and selenium is 3.13. Unfortunately, there is no change in the result. I'm still getting the same error. As far as  your stage 2 and 3 advice. I'm currently deploying to heroku so I do not have total control of the environment variables. Is there a way to make of these changes using python?

EDIT 2:

As I think about it more on https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation the example uses

```
from selenium import webdriver
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Nexus 5" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
                  desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
```

Are you suggesting the browser is at 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub'

Answer (score 18):

### ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

In general when a client terminates abruptly without closing the connection a `RST packet` is sent by the *TCP/IP* stack of the underlying OS. Python converts this into an exception with the text **Connection reset by peer**. As per your *error stack trace* it means that once `self._read_status()` was invoked (internally) *Python* assumed to receive something but the connection was suddenly dropped and *Python* informs you of this error by raising the exception:

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

The situation is somewhat similar to [this expression](https://everything2.com/title/Connection+reset+by+peer):

> "Connection reset by peer" is the TCP/IP equivalent of slamming the phone back on the hook. It's more polite than merely not replying, leaving one hanging. But it's not the FIN-ACK expected of the truly polite TCP/IP converseur.

There can be multiple probabilities behind this error as follows.

---

### Solution Stage A

A quick and a precise solution will be to add a few recommended *ChromeOptions* along with the existing one as follows:

```
options.add_argument("start-maximized"); // open Browser in maximized mode
options.add_argument("disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions"); // disabling extensions
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
```

and then

```
return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

**Note**: You need to remove the argument `options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')` as it is applicable to windows OS only.

---

### Solution Stage B

A couple of points:

- As per the documentation within [**`Python Chrome Mobile Emulation`**](https://gist.github.com/devinmancuso/ec8ae08fa73402e45bf1) the *Key* and *Value* pair seems to be **`"deviceName": "Google Nexus 5"`** (not `"deviceName": "Nexus 5"`)
- You can tweak you code to invoke `Remote()` through either of the following ways-

  - Invoking `Remote()` through `DesiredCapabilities()`:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    # import DesiredCapabilities was missing in your program
    from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

    mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Google Nexus 5" }
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities = capabilities)
    ```
  - You find a similar discussion on invoking `Remote()` through `ChromeOptions()` in [How to add selenium chrome options to 'desiredCapabilities'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075624/how-to-add-selenium-chrome-options-to-desiredcapabilities)
  - Invoking `Remote()` through `ChromeOptions()`:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "Google Nexus 5" }
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', options=chrome_options)
    ```
  - You find a similar discussion on invoking `Remote()` through `ChromeOptions()` in [Remote WebDriver UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492697/remote-webdriver-unreachablebrowserexception-could-not-start-a-new-session/49493787#49493787)
- For your reference here is the link to the documentation on [**`Webdriver.android`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_android/selenium.webdriver.android.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.android.webdriver)
- For your reference here is the link to the documentation on [**`Getting started with Selendroid`**](http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html#python)

---

### Solution Stage C

If you are still seeing the error, perform the following upgradation/cleanup tasks:

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.13.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.40**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v66-68*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.40 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### Solution Stage D

Looking out for a granular solution to specific error I stepped into [**Amazon S3 and "Connection Reset by Peer"**](http://scie.nti.st/2008/3/14/amazon-s3-and-connection-reset-by-peer/) where Garry Dolley summerizes the the cause of the problem to be a combination of the below mentioned factors:

- **TCP Window Scaling**
- **Linux kernels 2.6.17 or newer**

> Linux kernels 2.6.17+ increased the maximum size of the TCP window/buffer, and this started to cause other gear to wig out, if it couldn’t handle sufficiently large TCP windows. The gear would reset the connection, and we see this as a “Connection reset by peer” message.

A pottential solution will be to put the following entries within `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

- net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 512000
- net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 512000

**Note**: This fix is easy peasy, but it’ll slow your maximum throughput inexchange of faster downloads.

---

### PS

If applicable, ensure that /etc/hosts on your system contains the following entry :

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
```

---

### Related Discussions

Here are some of the related discussions:

- [Python socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981141/python-socket-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer)
- [Yet Another 'Connection reset by peer' Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874894/yet-another-connection-reset-by-peer-error)
- [Connection reset by peer [errno 104] in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111556/connection-reset-by-peer-errno-104-in-python-2-7)
- [Remote WebDriver UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492697/remote-webdriver-unreachablebrowserexception-could-not-start-a-new-session/49493787#49493787)
- [How to add selenium chrome options to 'desiredCapabilities'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075624/how-to-add-selenium-chrome-options-to-desiredcapabilities)

---

### References

Here are the references of this discussion:

- [Example Python Chrome Mobile Emulation Automated Unit Testing Using Selenium 2 WebDriver ChromeDriver](https://gist.github.com/devinmancuso/ec8ae08fa73402e45bf1)
- [Amazon S3 and "Connection Reset by Peer"](http://scie.nti.st/2008/3/14/amazon-s3-and-connection-reset-by-peer/)
- [How To: Network / TCP / UDP Tuning](https://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/~sparkst/howto/network_tuning.php)
- [How To : Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html)
- [Mobile Emulation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation)
- [selenium.webdriver.android.webdriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_android/selenium.webdriver.android.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.android.webdriver)
- [Getting started with Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html#python)

Comment: @user61629 Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Thank you for your help here. Based on Josh's response I have a follow up question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484680/how-to-find-a-browsers-command-executor-string-in-heroku . because it appears that 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub' is the default setting. I have not seen this in the heroku logs so there may be a different value

Comment: "deviceName": "Google Nexus 5"  - does not work, it gives a device not found selenium error in the logs. I have a github repo which I put at the top of the question if you don't mind looking at it.

Comment: Thank you again for your detailed answer. I'm awarding you the bounty, but unfortunately I am still not able to get it working.

Comment: docker run --sysctl those sysctl.conf changes if running into the issue using a Docker container (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54845286/2395133) I had to set `--sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0` for it to work. Playing with the tcp_rmem/wmem settings now to see if something else works. Fantastic answer. Been look for this for two weeks. Using gunicorn with geventwebsockets and websocket-client python libraries running into this issue on some Debian host VM and Ubuntu 18.04 based Docker image.

Answer (score 2):

The specific error message says

> **android**'s server IP address could not be found.

To me, that indicates that the browser is trying to lookup a DNS entry for `android`, which isn't a valid TLD. By chance, is the browser attempting to access `http://android`, rather than something like `https://www.google.com`? I can replicate that same error message in my own Chrome by typing `http://android` into the address bar. This leads me to believe that specifying a proper url for the browser should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Josh, its an interesting thought. I don't understand how to ' specify a proper url for the browser ' though. Can you give me an example?

Comment: In case you are interested I've created a github repo of my project stripped down which you can run on windows locally and that you could deploy to heroku quickly. details at top of question.